# Pandas index.get_loc giving keyerror for time series data

Tags: python, pandas, nsepy

The following code works fine.

```
import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np 
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
 from IPython import get_ipython 
 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

sym = 'SPY' 
df_close = pd.DataFrame() 
df_temp = pd.read_json('https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/'+sym+'/chart/5y') 
df_temp.set_index('date',inplace=True) 
df_close = df_temp['close']

loc = df_close.index.get_loc('2015-08-17')
```

I modified it to fetch data from nsepy package.i.e. replaced *read_json* line and commented *set_index* line as the data fetched from the package has the date line as index by default

```
import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import get_ipython
from datetime import date
from nsepy import get_history

get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

sym = 'SBIN'
df_close = pd.DataFrame()
df_temp = get_history(symbol=sym,
                   start=date(2014,1,1),
                   end=date(2018,3,24))
#df_temp.set_index('date',inplace=True)
df_close = df_temp['Close']

loc = df_close.index.get_loc('2015-08-17')
```

In both cases, df_close is a series and they have the date present in them. Only difference is that in the correct scenario it contains date in format like 
**2013-03-25 00:00:00**

Whereas in the incorrect one it is in format like **2014-01-01**

Here is the log.

> runfile('C:/Users/Arun/.spyder-py3/Practise
>   files/market_correction.py', wdir='C:/Users/Arun/.spyder-py3/Practise
>   files') Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/Arun/.spyder-py3/Practise files/market_correction.py', wdir='C:/Users/Arun/.spyder-py3/Practise
>   files')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Arun\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 705, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Arun\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/Arun/.spyder-py3/Practise
>   files/market_correction.py", line 27, in 
>       loc = df_close.index.get_loc('2015-08-17')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Arun\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
>   line 2527, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
>
> File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>
> File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>
> File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>
> File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>
> KeyError: '2015-08-17'

What am I doing wrong? The day is present in the series.

I have tried df.loc method as well, but that gives other errors.

I am using anaconda spyder with python 3.6

Solution :

```
import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import get_ipython
from datetime import date
from nsepy import get_history

get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

sym = 'SBIN'
df_close = pd.DataFrame()
df_temp = get_history(symbol=sym,
                   start=date(2014,1,1),
                   end=date(2018,3,24))

**df_temp.reset_index(drop = False, inplace = True)
df_temp['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df_temp['Date'])
df_temp.set_index('Date',inplace=True)**
df_close = df_temp['Close']

loc = df_close.index.get_loc('2015-08-17')
```

Comment: If in second code uncomment `df_temp.set_index('date',inplace=True)` it working?

Comment: It was giving keyerror for 'Date'. worked after dropping the index and then reindexing it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and maybe convert to datetimes, because `KeyError` means there is no value `2015-08-17` in index:

```
#check if DatetimeIndex
print (df_temp.index)

#if necessary convert column to index
df_temp.set_index('date',inplace=True) 
#if necessary convert to datetimes
df_temp.index= pd.to_datetime(df_temp.index)

loc = df_temp.index.get_loc('2015-08-17')
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I had to drop the index and then reindex it though.

df_temp = get_history(symbol=sym,
                   start=date(2014,1,1),
                   end=date(2018,3,24))

df_temp.reset_index(drop = False, inplace = True)
df_temp['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df_temp['Date'])
df_temp.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
df_close = df_temp['Close']

loc = df_close.index.get_loc('2015-08-17')

Comment: @ArunKamath - I check your code, maybe `df_temp.reset_index(drop = False, inplace = True)` should be omit too.